# How to enable sounds for Cortana on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I very recently installed Windows 10 on my PC, and now I'm testing Cortana. I have followed some tutorials. The problem is that Cortana responds to me only by text. I want Cortana to respond with her voice.

How can I enable voice on Cortana?

[image]

Comment: If you use text, she responds with text. If you use voice/mic, she uses voice.

Comment: @MC10 isn't there anyway that i use text and force her to use voice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Cortana will only respond by voice if you speak to her by voice.

- If you'd like a voice response, press <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or click on the microphone icon and speak to Cortana through your microphone. If enabled, you can also just say "Hey Cortana".

Comment: isn't there anyway that i use text and force her to use voice?

Comment: Sadly, I don't see a setting in Cortana that can be changed to enable this. A future update may add such a setting, but I wouldn't hold my breath on it.

Comment: i finally try `hey cortana plz speck` but doesn't work. plz notify me if you find how to do it

Comment: Did you type `Hey Cortana please speak` or say it out loud?

Answer (score 0):

Check what your sound is set to like if it is running through speakers or a headset, if it  is running through speakers and no speakers are plugged in you wont hear a thing, just make sure it is on the correct setting you can go through sound system or the volume  icon at the bottom of your screen.

that is what happened to me my setting was on the wrong one and I couldn't hear cortana.